# Cannot create a new GUI class in Eclipse Neon (4.6)?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, jface, windowbuilder, eclipse-neon

I am relatively new to GUI work, I installed windowbuilder into eclipse neon and everything shows up as it is supposed to. Except when I create a new project I cannot access the New > Other > GUI area for making a new GUI class. Any suggestions??

UPDATE (SOLVED): I got some outside assistance. For anyone wondering about this though, its pretty simple. In Neon, when you go to Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites and add a new site you have to add AND 'RELOAD' the release version AND THEN the integration version of window builder. I uninstalled everything and did it all over again in the right order. Must have mixed something up on the way the first time. But thanks guys.

Comment: Did you create it as a Java Project?

Comment: Yes, and when right clicking on the source folder to make a class, I should be able to go to new > other > GUI and find the gui class. The GUI folder doesn't even show up.